# How to join mixed list (array) (with integers in it) in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list (array) with mixed

```
a = ["x", "2", "y"]
b = ["x", 2, "y"]
print ":".join(a)
print ":".join(b)
```

The first join works, but the second one throws a TypeError exception

I came up with this, but is this the Python solution?

```
print ":".join(map(str, b))
```

BTW in the end I just would like to write this string to a file, so if there is a specific solution for that, I'd appreciate that too.

Comment: Yes, this is probably the most Pythonic way to do it.

Comment: Either what you have if you prefer brevity, or a `try/except` loop to normalize all the inputs before `join`ing them if you (arguably) prefer clarity.

Comment: Looks quite pythonic to me!

Comment: @sr2222 You mean catching a TypeError for every single value and handling it separately, although you know that there are non-string values in it? Exceptions are supposed to be exceptional.

Comment: @sr2222: I don't see how a `try/except` would help in normalizing the inputs.

Comment: Exception-based duck type handling, as you see in lots of Python code.  As I said, it's arguably another equal, but not better approach to take.  Also, if you expect most of your `join`ed values to already be strings, mapping all of them through `str` is wasteful, though you are starting to talk about premature optimization there.

Comment: One note on terminology -- What you have is a *list*, not an *array*.  When people say "array" they're usually referring to a `numpy.ndarray`, but there's also a built-in `array` module which supplies an `array` type (which can only hold homogeneous data)

Comment: @mgilson In my experience, when people say “array”, they usually mean the language agnostic data structure that an array in most languages is.

Comment: @mgilson thanks for the terminology comment. I changed it in the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your solution works nicely and is probably one of the fastest ways to do this for small to medium sized lists, but it creates an unnecessary list (in python2.x).  Usually that's not a problem, but in a few cases, depending on the object `b`, it could be an issue.  Another which is lazy in python2 as well as python 3 is:

```
':'.join(str(x) for x in b)
```

Some timings for python 2.7.3:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'b = ["x", 2, "y"]' '":".join(map(str,b))'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 usec per loop
$python -m timeit -s 'b = ["x", 2, "y"]' '":".join([str(x) for x in b])'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'b = ["x", 2, "y"]' '":".join(str(x) for x in b)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.26 usec per loop
$python -m timeit -s 'from itertools import imap; b = ["x", 2, "y"]' '":".join(imap(str,b))'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.83 usec per loop
```

Some timings for python3.2:

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'b = ["x", 2, "y"]' '":".join(map(str,b))'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.6 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'b = ["x", 2, "y"]' '":".join([str(x) for x in b])'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.08 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'b = ["x", 2, "y"]' '":".join(str(x) for x in b)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.39 usec per loop
```

Note that if you let the loop get a lot bigger, the differences become less important:

python2.7.3:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'b = list(range(10000))' '":".join(str(x) for x in b)'
100 loops, best of 3: 4.83 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'b = list(range(10000))' '":".join([str(x) for x in b])'
100 loops, best of 3: 4.33 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'b = list(range(10000))' '":".join(map(str,b))'
100 loops, best of 3: 3.29 msec per loop
```

python 3.2.0

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'b = list(range(10000))' '":".join(str(x) for x in b)'
100 loops, best of 3: 6.42 msec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'b = list(range(10000))' '":".join([str(x) for x in b])'
100 loops, best of 3: 5.51 msec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'b = list(range(10000))' '":".join(map(str,b))'
100 loops, best of 3: 4.55 msec per loop
```

*all timings done on my MacbookPro, OS-X 10.5.8 intel core2duo ....

Notes,

- python2.x is faster than python3.x in all cases (for me)
- List-comprehension turns out to be fastest for your example list, but `map` is faster for a larger list.  `map` is probably slower for the small list as you need to look up the function whereas the list comprehension cannot be "shadowed", so no lookup needs to be performed.  There may be another turn-around point for *HUGE* lists where the time it takes to build the intermediate list becomes significant.
- generator expression is always the slowest (but lazy in both cases)

Comment: if you import `itertools.imap` you can get the same performance gain: `':'.join(imap(str, b))`

Comment: @David -- `imap` does better than the generator, but still much worse than `map` for this small example (and it's only available in python2.x).  Thanks for the suggestion though.  I've added it to the timings.

Comment: I'm happy to improve this answer if you leave a suggestion :-)

Comment: `itertools.imap` is only available in python2 because in python 3 `map` *is* `itertools.imap`, to get the old one back, you would need `list(map(...))`