# neo4j, bulbs and utf8

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, neo4j

I am having some trouble inserting and looking up data from neo4j using python's library bulbs. The problem has to do with character encoding. I get:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)
```

when trying to lookup a node in the index. I've googled for ways to change the character encoding in either neo4j of bulbs, but can't seem to find a way to do it.

**Edit**
Here's the code that reproduces the error:

```
from bulbs.model import Node
from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
from bulbs.property import String
import MySQLdb
import sys


class Topic(Node):
    element_type = 'node'
    name = String(nullable=False)


g = Graph()
g.add_proxy('topics', Topic)

con = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', db='wiki_new', charset='utf8')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT page_title FROM page')
while True:
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if not row:
        break

    sys.stdout.write(row[0] + '\n')
    nds = g.topics.index.lookup(name=row[0])
    if not nds:
        g.topics.create(name=row[0])
```

The string that causes the error is: !Xóõ .

**UPDATE**

I'm getting the data from a XML file now (a Wikipedia page dump), using python's sax parser. The code is basically the same, and the error I get:

```
  File "graph.py", line 197, in <module>
    build_wikipedia_graph(WIKI_DUMP_PATH)
  File "graph.py", line 195, in build_wikipedia_graph
    filter_handler.parse(open(wiki_dump_path))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/saxutils.py", line 255, in parse
    self._parent.parse(source)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 304, in end_element
    self._cont_handler.endElement(name)
  File "/home/pedro/wiki/1.0/page_parser.py", line 55, in method
    getattr(self._downstream, method_name)(*a, **k)
  File "/home/pedro/wiki/1.0/page_parser.py", line 87, in endElement
    self.pageCallBack(self.currentPage, self.callbackArgs)
  File "graph.py", line 181, in _callback
    kgraph.set_links_to(page.title, target)
  File "graph.py", line 59, in set_links_to
    topic_dst = self._g.topics.get_or_create('name', topic_dst, name=topic_dst)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/element.py", line 607, in get_or_create
    vertex = self.index.get_unique(key, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/neo4jserver/index.py", line 335, in get_unique
    resp = lookup(self.index_name,key,value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py", line 878, in lookup_vertex
    path = build_path(index_path, vertex_path, index_name, key, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/utils.py", line 126, in build_path
    segments = [quote(str(segment), safe='') for segment in args if segment is not None]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The error occurs when I try to create a node with name: atp-toernooi van montréal/toronto .

**Another update**
With the updated bulbs library, I get a different error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/utils.py", line 129, in build_path
    segments = [quote(unicode(segment), safe='') for segment in args if segment is not None]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1238, in quote
    return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
KeyError: u'\xe9'
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide example code so I can see what's happening.

Comment: @espeed Added some code that causes the same error when creating the node. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Please post the full error message so I can see where in the stack it's happening.

Comment: What does the encoding in the XML doc say? Example: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` And what is the sax code you are using to parse it?

Comment: The code I'm using is taken from here: https://github.com/gareth-lloyd/visualizing-events/blob/master/wikipedia_processor/page_parser.py . I have no problems storing this in a SQL database... Thanks again!

Comment: @espeed Any more ideas? Printing the types of the objects I'm inserting, it's all unicode.

Comment: @espeed Why the call to str in your build_path method?

Comment: Because you can't join a list of mixed types, and some paths contain integer IDs. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954222/how-to-join-mixed-list-array-with-integers-in-it-in-python

Comment: However, that that `str` function needs to be `unicode` like here: https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/json.py#L13 -- I'll update the code and push it to GitHub and PyPi.

Comment: @espeed I get a different error now that has to do with the quote method of urllib. See the original post for update. Maybe add a encode('utf8') ?

Answer (score 0):

Bulbs stores strings as unicode in Neo4j Server -- notice the property type String is casts values to unicode (unicode strings are the default in Python 3):

- https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/property.py#L171

See the Python Unicode HOWTO:

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#python-2-x-s-unicode-support

First, verify your MySQL server has UTF-8 support:

`mysql> show character set like 'utf%';`

Also, notice my changes and comments...

```
from bulbs.model import Node
from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
from bulbs.property import String
import MySQLdb
import sys


class Topic(Node):
    element_type = 'node'           # by convention name this 'topic'
    name = String(nullable=False)


g = Graph()
g.add_proxy('topics', Topic)

# Make sure use_unicode to set True
con = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', db='wiki_new', use_unicode=True, charset='utf8')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT page_title FROM page')
while True:
    row = cur.fetchone()  
    if not row:
        break

    sys.stdout.write(row[0] + '\n')

    # Use Bulbs' get_or_create method to simplify your code
    nds = g.topics.get_or_create(name, row[0], name=row[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't try that solution because my data source changed to an XML file, but I'm still getting the same error. Please see the original post. Thanks for the tips!